# attributes missing after inserting a column into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

To add some information to individual elements in a data frame i used to assign attributes as shown

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4]], columns=['a','b'])
>>> df.a.label = 'foo'
>>> df.b.label = 'bar'
>>> print df.a.label, df.b.label
foo bar
```

However if i insert a new column and repeat the same procedure the new attribute is stored but old attributes are lost

```
>>> df.c.label = 'c'
>>> df['c'] = [5,6]
>>> df.c.label = 'c label'
>>> print df.c.label
'c label'
>>> print df.a.label
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'label'
```

Why is that and can i do about it?

Comment: So `print df.c.label` worked the first time and not the second?

Comment: most pandas operations produce a new frame with copied elements. attributes are NOT preserved in these copies. adding arbitrary attributes is not a good idiom in general. you could keep another column with your attributes as strings if that helps.